# Java Swing bug with JMenuBar, JScrollPane and Windows Look And Feel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

My problem is when I add a JScrollPane to a empty JPanel (JPanel attached to JFrame with JMenuBar) with Windows Feel and Look, this happens:

JScrollPane does not cover the entire JPanel:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6lDW.png]

This doesnt happen with the Cross Platform Feel and Look:

With Cross Platform Feel and Look covers all:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQvcJ.png]

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
         UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }


        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
            frame.setSize(600, 400);

            JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

            JMenu menu = new JMenu("Test");
            menuBar.add(menu);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(panel);

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
            panel.add(scrollPane);

            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

There is a fix or is my code?

Comment: *with Windows Feel and Look* - the code you posted doesn't set the Windows LAF.

Comment: oops sorry, i copied without it

Comment: @camickr fixed it, thanks for telling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an empty border as :

```
scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

[image: it's working for me]

Comment: Thank you men, i didnt knew that method.